# How to set nginx reverse proxy in remote server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I have one server Server-1 where my app server is running.
In Server-2 I want to set up my Nginx to act as a reverse proxy for my app server.

1. how do I set up Nginx(in Server-2) which forwards traffic to Server-1
2. how do I check that everything is working fine, Nginx(Server-2) is acting as a reverse proxy for my app server(Server-1)

Traffic--->Server-2(with Nginx reverse proxy)--->Server-1(with server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You should add location that will be redirecting all traffic from Server-2 to Server-1, e.g.:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     Server-2.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://Server-1.com/;
    }
}
```

2) Try load http://Server-2.com page and if everything fine, you will get response from your app on Server-1.com

Comment: is that necessary to mention server_name? @metallic

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN no, it's not necessary.